# Check not records exist for one to many in Symfony/Doctrine

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, query-builder

I have a relationship that is one to many. I have maps (each block is a separate map) and rooms (each map will have multiple rooms). So for the entities (I will cut out info not needed) I have:

```
/**
 * Block
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="BLOCK")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Block
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="PK", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SEQ_GET_BLOCK_PK", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Rooms", mappedBy="blockId")
     */
    private $pk;
}

/**
 * Rooms
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="ROOMS", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="IDX_EB2CE87E9B70DE02", columns={"MAP_ID"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Rooms
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="PK", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="SEQUENCE")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="SEQ_GET_ROOMS_PK", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
     */
    private $pk;

    /**
     * @var \Block
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Block")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="BLOCK_ID", referencedColumnName="PK")
     * })
     */
    private $block;
```

Now to get what block belongs to a room, that's simple, in the controller:

```
$roomRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Rooms');
$rooms = $roomRepo->findAll();
```

and in Twig (where fieldname is another field in the block table):

```
{% for room in rooms %}
    {{ room.block.fieldname }}
{% endfor %}
```

However, to display a list of blocks and show the rooms under them becomes harder. I would like to be able to get the list of blocks and do something in Twig like:

```
{% for block in blocks %}
    {% for room in block.rooms %}
        {{ room.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

In this situation, I am trying to get a list of blocks that do not have any rooms under them. If the solution above worked, I could just do a count of rooms in each block and only display if there is none. The other option is to make the query do the count in createQueryBuilder and return the entity block with the correct results.

Any ideas? I keep looking down these paths but hit walls after a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you need One-to-Many bidirectional relation: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional

Is the `$pk` property in `Block` a primary key? Then it can't have the annotation `@ORM\OneToMany` and you should have a separate property with a collection of rooms:

```
/** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Rooms", mappedBy="block") */
private $rooms;
```

and then on `Room` class:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Block", inversedBy="rooms")
 * @JoinColumn(name="BLOCK_ID", referencedColumnName="PK")
 */
private $block;
```

Your use case seems exactly the same like the one in the documentation so I recommend following their example.

Comment: I upvoted this as it is the correct answer, just not really an option for my solution (don't want to add an extra field in this case and because of how it is updated would be a pain to maintain). In future for a 1 to many that is the way to go, for this case I implemented some more complex sql with a manual join to get around this.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the solution Martin posted, it is the way to go, however, in my case I decided to add a more complex query to get the results I wanted. The query ended up looking like:

```
$blockRepo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Blocks');
$query = $blockRepo->createQueryBuilder('b')
    ->select('b')
    ->leftJoin("AppBundle:Rooms", "r", "WITH", "b.pk=r.block")
    ->where("b.location = :locationId")
    ->andWhere("r.pk IS NULL")
    ->setParameter("locationId", $locationId)
    ->getQuery();
$blocks = $query->getResult();
```

I actually did this in a custom function in a repository, but this code should work. As far as the 2 lines (where and setParameter) with the locationId, that was just because I wanted to select by another field as well, if these 2 lines are left out, it would just select all blocks with no rooms.